# How to create a Webhook between Google chat and Azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, webhooks, google-chat

Is it possible to connect a Google Chat room using Azure devOps WebHooks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Web Hooks in Azure DevOps provide a way to **send a JSON representation of an event to any public endpoint (HTTP or HTTPS)**.

But it's not able to directly contact Google chat room with Azure DevOps. Cause DevOps sends a JSON message in a format that Chat is not able to understand. Which means they do not talk to each other by default.

We need a way to transform the message and tie those two services together. There are a lot of options for that. We could use a 3rd-party tool Zapier.

> It allows to easily integrate various services and APIs and I highly
> recommend it, although it is a subject for another post.

You could refer this step by step tutorial--  [Azure DevOps integration with Google Hangouts Chat](https://dev.to/ib1/azure-devops-integration-with-google-hangouts-chat-3imn)